# Vue component won't load: did you register the component correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My router has:

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [{
            path: '/',
            name: 'login',
            component: Login,
        },
        {
            path: '/app',
            component: Container,
            children: [{
                path: '',
                name: 'home',
                component: Home
            }]

        },
    ],
});
```

My `Container.vue` has:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Navigation />
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navigation from "./Navigation.vue";
export default {
  name: "Container",
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
};
</script>
```

But I get an error:

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
>
> found in
>
> --->  at src/components/Container.vue
>           at src/App.vue

In my `Navigation.vue`, I have

```
<template>
  <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column flex-sm-row">
    <a class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
    <a class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link" href="#">Longer nav link</a>
    <a class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    <a
      class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link disabled"
      href="#"
      tabindex="-1"
      aria-disabled="true"
    >Disabled</a>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Navigation"
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing to add `components:{Navigation}` in `Container.vue` component

```
export default {
  name: "Container",
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
components:{Navigation}
};
```

Comment: You're my hero! That was less than 5 min!